# localhost doesn't resolve in Airplane Mode on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, localhost

I'm trying to do some local development on my laptop during some long flights, but when I put my laptop in Airplane Mode, Windows 10 can't seem to resolve `localhost`.

If my test server uses 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it works fine, and when I turn Wi-Fi back on, it works fine as well.

I can ping `localhost` in Airplane Mode and it resolves correctly as well. Disconnecting from all networks with Airplane Mode off seems to have the same issue.

Any ideas how I can do **offline development** on Windows 10?

Comment: This isn't a new problem.  This is how `localhost` has always worked.  I remember having this problem all the way back to Windows 98.

Comment: `localhost` doesn’t depend on external name resolvers. There’s clearly something wrong here. How did you try to resolve the address?

Comment: Looks like this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997442/nodejs-cannot-resolve-localhost-on-windows